# NSArray arrayWithObjects: limited to nine objects

Tags: xcode, nsarray

I'm getting apparently inconsistent behavior from NSArray arrayWithObjects: I'm trying to create a 19 element array but my line of code creates only nine elements. A test using strings works. Here's what I'm seeing.

```
cellButtonsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", 
                    @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z",
                    @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", @"z", nil];

NSLog(@"count of cellButtonsArray = %i", [cellButtonsArray count]);
```

The output is: "count of cellButtonsArray = 19"   //This is test code and is fine.

My real code uses objects which are UIButtons which are declared in the header. If I use two arrays of nine elements each, all is well. However, the following code throws no warnings or errors and works for the first nine cells. The rest are ignored.

```
cellButtonsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell0, cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4,
                   cell5, cell6, cell7, cell8, cell9, cell10, cell11, cell12, cell13,
                   cell14, cell15, cell16, cell17, cell18, nil];

NSLog(@"count of cellButtonsArray = %i", [cellButtonsArray count]);
```

The output is: "count of cellButtonsArray = 9"

Clearly, the count is not what I expect. The array works correctly with fewer than nine objects. Otherwise everything works, except for the nine buttons (cells) which aren't updated. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Is cell9 nil when you create the array?

arrayWithObjects stops adding objects when it hits any nil, not just the nil you specified at the end.

Comment: As he says, try before the cellbuttonsarray creation NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", cell8,cell9,cell10]; If one of those is nil then thats ur answer

Comment: Amazing! I think you solved my problem. Cell9 is just a dummy which isn't connected to anything or initiated anywhere. It's just there so  I can enumerate through the array without a gap between cell8 and cell10. I'll test it out and get back to you. Even if this doesn't solve the problem, it's impressive that you saw that issue so quickly.

Comment: Yup! That was it. I got rid of cell9 and inserted a second cell8 and life is good. Thanks guys.